# Dealing with advertisement-esque but potentially useful posts by the creator of a library

Tags: discussion, advertising

Take a look at the [gridgain](/questions/tagged/gridgain) tag (click image to enlarge):

[image: screenshot]

It appears that the creator of this library is posting tons of questions that look kind of like advertisements. For example, question (asked by this user):

> I need to add my own jar files to classpath when running GridGain, what's the easiest way to do that?

And answer (self-answered):

> Starting from 2.1.0 GridGain supports adding user JAR files without changing class paths or any shell scripts. Just put your JAR files into the `$GRIDGAIN_HOME/libs/ext` directory. This directory will be scanned when GridGain starts and all libraries will be added to the classpath automatically.

---

What should we do in these types of situations? I'd hesitate to say "delete," because these are potentially useful, but they do seem kind of self-promotional, and SO is not a blog.

Comment: @asawyer That's the thing - it seems spammy, but it might help future visitors, and we don't want to remove useful content.

Comment: I see your point and removed the comment.

Comment: With my (limited) experience on SO, I think that they aren't necessarily breaking the rules. I'm not saying behavior like this should encouraged, but in my opinion they don't merit closing/deletion.

Comment: A lot of those questions are of dubious quality or are not really programming related. I closed a few, asking them to just make a FAQ on their own site. The rest are not great questions, but I can't justify a binding close vote. I'll let others vote on them.

Comment: Urk.  If there wasn't a use case for "... because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem," this would totally be the definition.  Those are all horrible questions that are unanswerable as-is.